# Center absolute block in td vertically

Tags: html, css

I have such code:

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px 20px;
}
.hint {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:800px">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <span>text</span>
      <div class="hint">
        <span class="recomendation">Some text with recomendation</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>text</span>
      <div class="hint">
        <span class="recomendation">Some text with recomendationSome text with recomendationSome text with recomendation</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/JVkXP3vNtIj4gzwwjm4B?p=preview

But i have one issue, which i can't resolve:

Is it possible to center yellow block vertically? (it should be positioned absolutely, it height can be only as text height is. Without line-height, height is dynamic!). Now it's attached to the top, and i can't attach it to the center somehow. Is it possible without using JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox). All modern browsers support it, with [prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) it also works in IE10.

```
.hint {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px 20px;
}
.hint {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:800px">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      <span>text</span>
      <div class="hint">
        <span class="recomendation">Some text with recomendation</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>text</span>
      <div class="hint">
        <span class="recomendation">Some text with recomendationSome text with recomendationSome text with recomendation</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work regardless of content height!

```
.hint {
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 100px;
}
.recomendation{
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/URIFrwBxvX3V7hvRT5km?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This is a nifty little trick:

```
.hint {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 100px;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

The key here is `transform`.

It can also be used to center things horizontally too.

[This page](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/) shows a good example.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to replicate your request:

```
.hint {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 44%;
    left: 100px;
}
```

I changed the top position, and deleted the bottom property.

Comment: This doesn't account for multiple lines, the 44% just works alright in this case.